# Show "Done" on keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have this code in my xml:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/totalamount"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
     android:ems="10"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
```

I have two EditText's on my main screen for the user to input values. When the user selects one of the EditText's to input a decimal number, the android keyboard appears to input the numbers, but instead of it saying **DONE** its says **Next** and it moves down to the next EditText box.

I want to have it so that when the user selects one EditText, no matter how many EditText fields there are on the main screen, the keyboard has DONE instead of NEXT so it doesnt move down all the EditText fields until it finally says DONE.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting the EditText `imeOptions`attribute to `actionDone`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions).